# Figuring out the type of machine learning problem

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, regression, classification

I am not able to figure out what kind of machine learning is this:

Training set: consists of sentences with object labels for object phrases
Example:

`"This is a black chair. It is next to a large bed."`

Phrases `'This', 'black chair', 'it'` were annotated with the label `"chair"` and phrase `'large bed'` was annotated with the label `'bed'`. There are 18 available labels that can be assigned.

For an unannotated sentence, I want to predict the labels for each phrase in the sentence.

For example:

`There is a study table in the corner of the room, behind it is a small chair.`

I would like the model to predict a label (available 18 labels) for each phrase that represents an object in the above sentence.

Expected output:

`'study table', 'it' -----> label 'table'`

`'small chair' -----------> label 'chair'`

So, for each sentence, there could be more than one output label. Labels are not associated with sentence, but with phrases in the sentence.

Is this a classification, regression, or a different kind of problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 2):

Contrarily to other response, I think this is a task of coreference resolution. As it seem you need to link 'black chair' to 'it'.
The task of named entity recognition, is to find entities in a text, a person name, a date, a company's name. See [named entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity) and [named entity recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition).

The task of coreference resolution is to find which phrase is linked to a undetermined subjet. I am by no mean a linguistic or coreference resolution expert .
Thus I do not know what methods are used to tackle this task.